# Replace SRC attribute with data-original

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lazy-loading

I have installed LazyLoad in my WordPress theme. I'd like to change all SRC attributes of images that use lazyload to data-original.

This:

```
<img class="lazy" src="something.png">
```

To this:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="something.png">
```

I have tried many things. Right now, this is what I have:

```
$( 'img.lazy[src]' ).attr('src').replaceWith( 'data-original' );
```

How do I replace the SRC attribute to data-original?

Comment: Please read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr) before asking questions here.

Comment: Not to be rude but, if you spent a minute reading the docs you would've noticed that your code makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Then how do I do it? It's not the only thing I've tried

Comment: I had already read the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
$( 'img.lazy[src]' ).attr('src').replaceWith( 'data-original' );
```

To this:

```
$("img.lazy").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-original",$(this).attr("src"));
    $(this).removeAttr("src");
});
```

Comment: Code syntax is valid but the whole thing makes no sense. He need to change his server side code for correct lazy loading behaviour.

Comment: You could shorten the code within the function with: `$(this).attr("data-original",$(this).attr("src")).removeAttr("src");`